# Calling the Azure Storage REST API directly from PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

Now that the [Azure Storage PHP client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php) is deprecated, [Microsoft recommends](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/retirement-notice-the-azure-storage-php-client-libraries-will-be-retired-on-17-march-2024/) calling the Azure Storage REST API directly. The only problem is, I have no idea where to start with doing this through PHP, and basically all the documentation I come across through Google and searching SO/SE is related to using the aforementioned composer client libraries.

Does anyone have a working example of how to, for example, upload a PDF attachment to a blob storage container **by calling the API directly using PHP**?

I've tried finding documentation specific to PHP on this subject and I have so far come up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Upload a PDF attachment to a blob storage container **by calling the API directly using PHP**?

You can use the below PHP code to upload the pdf file by calling the API directly.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$storageAccountname = 'your storage account name';
$accesskey = "your storage account access key";
$filepath = realpath('./sample1.pdf');
$containerName = 'test';
$blobName = 'demo.pdf';

$URL = "https://$storageAccountname.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";

function uploadBlob($filepath, $storageAccountname, $containerName, $blobName, $URL, $accesskey) {

    $Date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
    $handle = fopen($filepath, "r");
    $fileLen = filesize($filepath);

    $headerResource = "x-ms-blob-cache-control:max-age=3600\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12";
    $urlResource = "/$storageAccountname/$containerName/$blobName";

    $arraysign = array();
    $arraysign[] = 'PUT';               /*HTTP Verb*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Encoding*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Language*/  
    $arraysign[] = $fileLen;            /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-MD5*/  
    $arraysign[] = 'application/pdf';   /*Content-Type*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Date*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Modified-Since */  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Match*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-None-Match*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Range*/  
    $arraysign[] = $headerResource;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
    $arraysign[] = $urlResource;        /*CanonicalizedResource*/

    $str2sign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

    $sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($str2sign)), base64_decode($accesskey), true));  
    $authHeader = "SharedKey $storageAccountname:$sig";

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: ' . $authHeader,
        'x-ms-blob-cache-control: max-age=3600',
        'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-date: ' . $Date,
        'x-ms-version: 2019-12-12',
        'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        'Content-Length: ' . $fileLen
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileLen); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo ('Uploaded successfully<br/>');
    print_r($result);

    curl_close($ch);
}

uploadBlob($filepath, $storageAccountname, $containerName, $blobName, $URL, $accesskey);
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Since the retired the php package, this really useful.