Transitioning from deprecated Azure PHP SDK to Azure CLI for blob storage operations
We have used the PHP SDK to download, list, and upload files to Azure Blob Storage. However, since Microsoft has deprecated the PHP SDK, our client has requested that we transition to the recommended solutions.
We attempted to use the Azure CLI command to upload a file. Here is the code we used:
az storage blob upload --account-name <account name> --container-name <container name> --name <blob name> --file <folder/sub-folder/file name> --sas-token DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account name>;AccountKey=<account key>

Unfortunately, it did not work. After searching on Stack Overflow, we found a link that assists with the upload process, partially solving our problem.
Calling the Azure Storage REST API directly from PHP
We are now trying to use this example to download files, but we are unsure what needs to be changed, apart from the URL, to download the file.
Update:
We found the download file solution on Stack Overflow. Here is the link.
Download blob using PHP using shared access key
We are still searching for Delete file API.

You can take inspiration from this example of using their REST API (example: upload to Azure blob)  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408667/calling-the-azure-storage-rest-api-directly-from-php

For the other functions, you'll have to develop them yourself. A good starting point:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-curl

To get help here you would need to ask a more specific, detailed question about a particular problem in your code. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue

See also Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?

I need example...why, what have you tried and where have you stuck? You may have altered the specific language of your question but the issue with it is still essentially the same - it's too broad and there's no obvious effort on your part to research or attempt anything. We're not a free write-my-code or find-a-tutorial service. We expect that you make a reasonable attempt to research and write something yourself, before asking. Or if you can't, you need to make it very clear what specifically is causing you to be unable to write any code.

e.g. If you think documentation is unclear, give us a link to the documentation you're referring to and point out what you're unable to understand, and then maybe we can help on a specific point. Don't just ask us to start from the beginning or provide a fully worked example, because we don't know where your real pain point is or whether we're looking at the bit which is actually giving you difficulty right now - and because we shouldn't be asked to do things which you might already have done, or substitute for your general efforts. Thanks.

At a guess maybe your question is really "how do I make a HTTP request using PHP"...we don't know if you're stuck on that fundamental point, or on some more subtle aspect of interacting with specific endpoints in the API (for example). So we can't tailor any answer to your real needs.

N.B. Note that https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/retirement-notice-the-azure-storage-php-client-libraries-will-be-retired-on-17-march-2024/ says: "Support for the Azure Storage PHP client libraries is ending on 17 March 2024. Source code for the client libraries will remain open source. You can call the Azure Storage REST API directly or continue to directly code and apply your own fixes to the existing client libraries as required or continue to code and apply your own fixes to the existing client libraries as required" ...

... so actually there's nothing to stop you using a copy of the SDK and it should continue to operate correctly until such time as MS make a breaking change in the blob storage API. You'd just have to take some responsibility for any necessary bug fixes that you find are required in the SDK code (you could try to build an open-source community to help with that of course, if you fork the GitHub repo). Or at the very least you could read the SDK source code to see how it makes requests to the API, which could give you a starting point for writing your own version.

But it might be quicker to just keep using the SDK, and then fix it if anything goes wrong in future.

Thanks @ADyson. We are already using SDK for a while and client has asked us to move to API for the security reason. I'm Manager not into active development and I've junior developers working on it. I am trying to get some help for them. However, I understand. I will try to update question with more information.

Ultimately the SDK just calls the API anyway...it's simply a convenient way to make it easier to interact with the API using PHP. So if you replace it, you'll mostly likely simply end up with your own (possibly smaller) version of the same concept - I'd expect the result would be some PHP functions which allow your developers to easily make the needed calls to the API from the rest of their code, which they can re-use anywhere it's needed. Hence my suggestion to simply take the SDK code (or maybe just the parts you actually need in your apps) and start maintaining it yourself.

`I found this link that helps in upload, the problem is half solved.
Calling the Azure Storage REST API directly from PHP
We are trying to use this example to download, but not knowing what to change except URL`...well for that you'd have to read the API documentation for the "download" endpoint and see what it expects you to do when calling it. Do your developers have any previous experience of working with APIs? The procedure is pretty much the same every time - read the docs, find out how to authenticate, work out which data endpoint(s) you need, read how to interact with them.

I'm not particularly familiar with the Blob Storage API specifically, but I'd guess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id is what you'd be interested in??

P.S. It's often a good idea to use a tool such as Postman to model your API calls, so you can build the request visually, test it easily and get it working, before trying to write equivalent program code to make the same request. Postman, in fact, can auto-generate equivalent PHP code based on requests you build using it.


Update: We found the download file solution on Stack Overflow. We are still searching for the Delete file API.

You can use the code below to delete a blob from Azure Blob Storage using PHP.
Code:
<?php

$storageAccountName = 'venkat123';
$accessKey = "xxxx";
$containerName = 'test';
$blobName = 'venkat235.wav';

function deleteBlob($storageAccountName, $containerName, $blobName, $accessKey) {
    $URL = "https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";

    $Date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');

    $headerResource = "x-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12";
    $urlResource = "/$storageAccountName/$containerName/$blobName";

    $arraysign = array();
    $arraysign[] = 'DELETE';            /*HTTP Verb for deletion*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Encoding*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Language*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-MD5*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Type*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Date*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Modified-Since */
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Match*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-None-Match*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Unmodified-Since*/
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Range*/
    $arraysign[] = $headerResource;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
    $arraysign[] = $urlResource;        /*CanonicalizedResource*/

    $str2sign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

    $sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($str2sign)), base64_decode($accessKey), true));
    $authHeader = "SharedKey $storageAccountName:$sig";

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: ' . $authHeader,
        'x-ms-date: ' . $Date,
        'x-ms-version: 2019-12-12',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE'); // Setting request method to DELETE
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 202) { // 202 Accepted indicates successful deletion
        echo 'Blob deleted successfully.';
    } else {
        echo 'Failed to delete blob.';
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}

deleteBlob($storageAccountName, $containerName, $blobName, $accessKey);

Output:
Blob deleted successfully.


Reference:
Delete Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
